# Elementary Number Theory Proof Modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I am having trouble with this proof.

> If $a,b$ are integers, then $(a+b)^3 \equiv a^3 + b^3 \pmod{3}$

---

What I am confused about is using the definition of modulo. So can $b^3 \pmod{3}$ be written as $3\, |\, [b^3 - (a+b)^3]?$ How does the $a^3$ term come into play with writing the modulo definition.

Also I apologize for the messiness of the math equations, I am new to math exchange and haven't gotten the TeX concepts down yet.

Comment: By definition they are congruent $\!\bmod 3\iff 3$ divides their difference  $(a+b)^3-(a^3+b^3)\ \ $

Comment: mod 3 means the remainder of a number after (integer) division by 3. So 7 mod 3 is 1 ( $7=2 \times 3 +1$) and the equation means that $(a+b)^3$ and $a^3 + b^3$ will have the same remainder on division by $3$, i.e. their difference is divisible by 3. Which is clear, as that difference equals $3(a^2 b + a b^2)$...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Just expand $$(a+b)^3 = a^3+?+?+b^3$$